# C program crashes after pointer arithmetic (only in some computers)

Tags: c, pointers, crash

I have the following code (I didn't write it and it is simplified to only show the problematic part):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test_struct {
    unsigned int foo;
    char *dummy;
} test_struct;

int main()
{
    test_struct *s = (test_struct *) malloc(10 * sizeof(test_struct));
    s = (test_struct *)((unsigned long)s + 16);
    s->foo = 1; // crash!
}
```

The program allocates memory for 10 structs (10*24 bytes in my platform). Then, the pointer gets an addition of 16 bytes, and it tries to write a number in that position.

I have tested this snippet in 4 computers. Two of them are running on Windows 7 x64, and it works well. Another one running on lubuntu x64, and works as expected, too. The other one is a Windows 10 x64, and it crashes.

Could you help me to understand what is wrong in those lines? I'm using a third party library that does this and I don't know what is really happening.

Comment: Hos do you know that a structure is 24 bytes? And even if it is, then why do you think a pointer 16 bytes into the memory would be valid? Wouldn't adding an offset of 24 bytes (or whatever `sizeof(test_struct)` might be) would make more sense?

Comment: And what is the real problem that lead to this question? Why do you ask? What is the use-case for something like this?

Comment: That "works as expected" phrase is a little tricky. I assume it simply means you didn't see a crash. Just because the program "works as expected" doesn't mean it's not a bug. You could run this, not get a fault, but it could still be writing memory that it's not supposed to write.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I know the struct if 24 bytes because I printed the value in my tests. I expect the pointer would be valid because I allocated plenty of space (it won't work even if I allocate 5000 bytes). I agree it doesn't make much sense, but I didn't write the code, I'm trying to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: The problem isn't only about size, but about *alignment*. Some data can not be put on any address on some systems. On these platforms unaligned access could lead to exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> s = (test_struct *)((unsigned long)s + 16);

On some platforms `long` is not enough to store a pointer, so use `uintptr_t` instead:

```
s = (test_struct *)((uintptr_t)s + 16);
```

> The program allocates memory for 10 structs (10*24 bytes in my case). Then, the pointer gets an addition of 16 bytes

Whatever you are trying to achieve, please note the size of the structure is also platform dependent. Not only the fields inside the structure, but padding might also be different on different platforms.

So in calculations we better use `sizeof` and `offsetof` instead of magic numbers like `16`.

Comment: Notably, 64-bit Windows using the Visual C++ compiler is one of those platforms.

Comment: Thanks, Andriy. I said 10*24 bytes "in my case", because I printed the sizeof(struct) result to check how much memory was taking the struct. Also, the real library does not add a hardcoded value of 16 bytes, but I found out that in a given execution or a given setting it was 16 bytes when it crashed. What I don't understand is, if there is plenty of memory allocated, why it can't write a number even if it is not the initial position of the allocated part? I don't like the way this library is coded, but I have to fix it to run my program.

Comment: @ZuhaitzBeloki you can't write because you are casting to `unsingned long`, which might be just 32 bits on some platforms. You should use `uintptr_t` instead. See the beginning of my answer ;)

Comment: You were right, @AndriyBerestovskyy. It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

test_struct *s = (test_struct *) malloc(10 * sizeof(test_struct)); s = (test_struct *)((unsigned long)s + 16);

Multiple bug in your program:-
1.you should understand memory allocation is fully depend on OS .how and why you are doing increment of 16 by long it may overflow.
2.After changing address store in s you are acessing foo that is invalid now.
3.Using valgrind and check for invalid.